# How to get a return value from 2nd. Shell script execution in the 1st. Shell executed? (Unix Korn Shell)

Tags: shell, unix, return, return-value

I all

I want to know how to get a return value from 2nd. shell executed and save it in a variable in the first script.

something like this

1st script:

```
Result=$(. /dir/to/mysecond/shell/second_shell.sh "Blue")
echo ${Result}
```

2nd script:

```
if [ $1 == "Blue" ]; then
   return_value="The color is blue"
else
   return_value="The color is not blue"
fi

return ${return_value}
```

Result variable is empty in the first scrip, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`Result=$(…)` will store into `$Result` whatever is printed by the command in `$(…)` (not the return value) so instead of `return ${return_value}`, use `echo ${return_value}`.